# Extract the Name of the uploaded file into another columns with a flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, flow, formula

I want to extract the name of the file to another 6 columns.

For example, you want to put the "D" in the file name in the first column and the word "Berlin" in the second column, and so on.

I have already found a helpful solution with flows here in the forum, but I can't get any further with it.

I get the first part extracted, but it doesn't work from the second part on. I think I have a mistake in the definition of the formula/expression of the flow.

I hope you could help me.

**Here are the steps I have done so far.**

As you can see, the first five columns have " - " as delimiter and the last one only "-":

[image]

This my flow:

[image]

And here you will get the formula for part 1 **(works)** and 2 **(doesn´t work)**:

*Part 1 (extract the "D")*:

```
substring(triggerBody()?['{Name}'], 0, IndexOf(triggerBody()?['{Name}'],' - '))
```

*Part 2 (extract the "Berlin":*

```
substring(triggerBody()?['{Name}'], add(IndexOf(triggerBody()?['{Name}'],' - '),1), sub(sub(length(triggerBody()?['{Name}']),IndexOf(triggerBody()?['{Name}'],' - ')),1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Compose** action and [**Split** function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#split) to extract the Filename string into substrings using the delimiter `' - '`.

See the sample flow here:
[image]

And the expressions are:

**Compose**: `split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Name}'],' - ')`

**D**: `outputs('Compose')[0]`

**Berlin**: `outputs('Compose')[1]`

Note: Since you do not need the last substring “`2020-q*`”, I have left it un-splitted.

---

**UPDATE:**

To extract substrings from "`2020-q*`", you can add one more Compose action and two outputs from the second Compose action to the flow:

[image]

Expressions:

**Compose2**: `split(outputs('2020-q*'),'-')`

**2020**: `outputs('Compose2')[0]`

**q***: `outputs('Compose2')[1]`

Comment: Thanks for your help. That worked really well!
Do you still have a solution if I want to split "2020-q*" also?

Comment: @Ann-KathrinKaiser Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support!

Comment: @Ann-KathrinKaiser Glad it helps. Would you please accept it as answer if you later confirm it to be the solution? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well.